# Parsing a float from a string in different locales

Tags: c++, string

I want to parse a floating point value from a std::string where decimal separator is ".". How do I parse such floats in locales where the separator is ","? I'm using std::stringstream. To clarify: How do I force en-US style float parsing with stringstream?

Comment: Are you able to use C++11?  Also, do you mean that you want to parse floats with a `,` or a `.` as the separator, or both?  It seemed like you said two different things...

Comment: I'm using C++11 and my float strings only contain ".".

Comment: Ah, so your locality normally uses the `,` separator, but now you need to be able to handle the `.` separator in addition to the comma?

Comment: My locale uses "." and my strings contain "." But I want my strings to parse right in every locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the locale for your whole program to the basic "C" one this way:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

Or for a single stream:

```
std::locale c_locale("C");
my_stream.imbue(c_locale);
```

This will give you "old school," non-i18n parsing and printing.  You can try other locale names too, but the one two that are guaranteed to be available on all systems are "" and "C", and it seems like the latter works for your case.